# How to solve Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero?

Tags: java, exception, combinations

here is code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prob_c {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner x = null;
        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File("prob_c.in"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.print("File not found!");
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            int counter = 0;
            int n = x.nextInt();
            int r = x.nextInt();
            counter++;
            long res = 1;
            res = getFact(n) / (getFact(n - r) * getFact(r));
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }

    public static long getFact(int j) {
        long f = 1;
        for (int i = j; i >= 1; i--) {
            f *= i;
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: As simple as, writing an if condition which checks for zero. No way you can stop it.

Comment: This is NOT a bad question.  I believe the apparent division by zero is actually caused by an integer overflow in working out the factorials; not by an actual attempt to divide by zero.  It's a shame that everyone would rather down-vote or close-vote than post a helpful answer about integer overflows and using `BigInteger` instead of `long`.

Comment: Can you write the input which triggers the exception ? (the content of prob_c.in)

Comment: 5 3               
5 2 
5 5 
4 2 
10 7 
20 9 
52 5 
100 0 
75 30 
1 1 
28 18

two numbers per line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with big factorials, you'll need to use the `BigInteger` class, rather than `long` to store the numbers.

You can also work out `getFact(n) / (getFact(n - r) * getFact(r))` far more efficiently if you EITHER multiply all the numbers from `n` down to `n - r + 1` and then divide by `getFact(r)`, or multiply all the numbers from `n` down to `r + 1` and then divide by `getFact(n - r)`.

The reason you're getting a divide by zero error is that the binary expansions of factorials tend to end with lots of zeroes.  For example, if you write `20!` in binary, it ends with 18 zeroes (if I've counted correctly).  As you work out a factorial, every time you multiply by another even number, you get more zeroes on the end.

Now, if you take a number that ends in 64 or more zeroes, and try to fit it into a `long`, then everything but the last 64 digits will be truncated - this is integer overflow.  That means that `getFact(n - r) * getFact(r)` can be truncated to zero, if `n - r` or `r` is large enough.  That's where your division by zero error is coming from.